# Stack Overflow - no terms and conditions?

Tags: discussion, terms-of-service

I have not seen/accepted any term and conditions/terms of service in the sign up, or when posting.
There is a link to a privacy policy and a creative commons statement in the bottom of the pages. But no legal blah blah, is this a triumph of the common sense?

Makes me feel warm inside.

Comment: +1 to feeling warm :)

Comment: Makes me feel like no one at StackOverflow understands legal issues to even a trivial level.

Comment: @Daniel:  That's why I always recommend asking a lawyer about legal questions.  Are you a lawyer, or are you assuming things are just difficult?

Answer (score 10):

At the foot of every page there's this statement:

> user contributed content licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

plus the links to the [faqs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) on each site which have the following statement:

> #### Other people can edit my stuff?!
>
> Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Which I think just about covers everything.

Comment: Correct. User submitted content is magically licensed to StackOverflow under cc-wiki even though users never agree to license it. Actually, this is just what we assume. StackOverflow never even makes the slightest mention of what your license to them is assumed to be. They just say that they relicense your content under cc-wiki. It's all very magical and hand-wavy really. If StackOverflow ever got sued, they'd probably go down in a blaze of glory.

Comment: @Daniel:  StackOverflow can't relicense content, and can't add an additional license without having a license.  If you'd like to point to a court case about implicit licensing on a web forum, I'd be fascinated to find out how it went.

Answer (score 4):

At the bottom of every page, you'll find a link labelled "[legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal)", which will direct you to all of that heart-warming blah blah blah...

Comment: I curl up, every night, with a good legal document. Helps put me to sleep!

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter?

It is like lawyers brainwashing us to think that we really need ToS, licenses, and privacy policies.

Who reads them anyway?

Comment: It doesn't matter who reads them - it matters who agrees. It's a help when you get sued.

Comment: are most of the users of a website stupid to agree to something they dont read, or is it stupid the concept of term and conditions for a website.